# The Mui DataGrid table is not getting Responsive for mobile layout when I used the Mui MiniDrawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive-design, datagrid

there, Here I am using the  [MiniDrawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#mini-variant-drawer) Variant from Mui Drawer and I am also using the [Data Grid table](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/) form Mui x , here the problem is if I used the Data Grid table `without drawer` means its gets responsive for mobile and web , but when I used with the grid table with mui drawer means its `not getting responsive`

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2lXQ.png)

#### **Drawer.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import ValueGetterGrid from '../../components/display/GridTable';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  flexShrink: 0,
  whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  boxSizing: 'border-box',
  ...(open && {
    ...openedMixin(theme),
    '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
  }),
  ...(!open && {
    ...closedMixin(theme),
    '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
  }),
}));

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 5,
              ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Mini variant drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        <ValueGetterGrid />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

#### GridTable.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

function getFullName(params) {
  return `${params.row.firstName || ''} ${params.row.lastName || ''}`;
}

const columns = [
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
  { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: getFullName,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: getFullName,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: getFullName,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName',
    headerName: 'Full name',
    width: 160,
    valueGetter: getFullName,
  },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon' },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei' },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime' },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya' },
  { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys' },
];

export default function ValueGetterGrid() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

#### App.jsx

```
import { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import reactLogo from '../assets/react.svg';
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg';
//import './App.css';
import MiniDrawer from '../layouts/drawer/Drawer.jsx';
import ValueGetterGrid from '../components/display/GridTable';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MiniDrawer />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I just want to figure out why  Data grid table is not getting responsive

`All answers are helpful and appreciated.`